# write id of each element on page if the element has an id

Tags: javascript, jquery

need to write `id` of each element on page - if the element has `id`
in plain javascript or jquery - doesn't matter
here is my try - without success
pls help

```
$('body *').each(function(el){
    if(el.attr('id')){console.log(el.attr('id'));}
});
```

another try

```
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(el) {
    if(el.attr('id')){console.log(el.attr('id'));}
});
```

Comment: Check your console. What does it say? Hint: the first parameter of the callback for jQuery’s `.each` is the index. Use `this.id` for the jquery approach. For the native JS just use `el.id`.

Comment: @Terry - `this.id` - doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('*')
const elementsWithId = Array.from(elements).filter(element => element.id != '')
elementsWithId.forEach(element => console.log(element.id))
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="test">
    <p>No id</p>
    <p id="creative">Has id</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

- This issue with your code is the `el.attr('id')`. Replace it with `el.id`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this

```
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(el) {
    if(el.attributes.id){console.log(el.attributes.id);}
});
```